# File reading in C language

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read a file in C language

```
while(1){
        if(feof(file)){
            break;
        }
        printf("%c",fgetc(file));
    }
```

At the end I get special character like � I dont have anything like that in file

Comment: so what's the question here ?

Comment: What's the character's decimal representation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read a file step by step using the following code:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    putchar(ch);
}
```

This special character might be the [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/EOF/?kw=EOF).

This [question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) might be interesting for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for fgetc:

```
RETURN VALUE
       fgetc(),  getc()  and getchar() return the character read as an
       unsigned char cast to an int or EOF on end of file or error.
```

So you should check for feof before you use the return value of fgetc or you will print out the `EOF` character:

```
while(1){
        int c = fgetc(file);
        if(feof(file)){
            break;
        }
        printf("%c",c);
    }
```